# Why does this reCaptcha javascript not work?

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

See jsfiddle app https://jsfiddle.net/dciwill/m3psLpqm/5/

```
<head>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<scrypt type="text/javascript">
function recaptchaCallback() {
$('#submit1').attr('onclick="return ctypeY()"');
$('#submit2').attr('onclick="return ctypeN()"');
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan=4>
    <input name="submit1" id="submit1" type=button class="subbutton" alt="Include EZPAY Processing Fees" value="Include EZPAY Processing Fees">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4" >
    <input name="submit2" id="submit2" type=button alt="Exclude EZPAY Processing Fees" class="subbutton2" value="Exclude EZPAY Processing Fees">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" data-sitekey="6Lf0CiAUAAAAAH0PwOQd7QExyVQb3gx_8lTLtJ0x" align="center"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

I am trying to add the attributes to the submit buttons after reCaptcha is verified.

Comment: @TyQ. No, [codereview.se] is for code that works. See https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/13492.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sorry I'm not familiar with that StackExchange site. I just hear people talking about it. Figured this type of question related to those other questions.

Comment: @Will, please read [the documentation for `attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value) for the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks Mike McCaughan, it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mike McCaughan...

```
function recaptchaCallback() {
$('#submit1').attr({onclick: "return ctypeY()"});
$('#submit2').attr({onclick: "return ctypeN()"});
};
```